# Remove List elements selected in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` based on table model that uses a `List`, I would like to delete elements that are selected in this `JTable`, from the `List`, the `JTable` is sortable, so when i get selected rows, I can't simply list.remove, because order is different. Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) methods `convertRowIndexToView` and `convertRowIndexToModel`:

> The selection is always in terms of JTable so that when
>   using RowSorter you will need to convert using convertRowIndexToView
>   or convertRowIndexToModel. 
>   The following shows how to convert coordinates from JTable to that of
>   the underlying model:
>
> ```
>   int[] selection = table.getSelectedRows();
>   for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
>     selection[i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[i]);
>   }
>   // selection is now in terms of the underlying TableModel
> ```

Check out [How to Use Tables # Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for some examples.